# How to make a file edit permanent

Tags: files, filesystem

I recently edited some files, and i'd like for that change to be permanent. Not something as simple as setting the owner to root, but rather, making so *I* have no way possible to edit or remove said file.

Comment: If you have the power to make something permanent, then you also have the power to make it impermanent. Ubuntu will not protect you from yourself.

Comment: If an edit to a file is that important to you make a backup of the file in a safe location.  Having sudo / admin rights you can always edit a file regardless.  Even adding the file to a partition somewhere then making it Read Only, you can still edit the file by a simple remount of the partition back to Read Write.

Comment: The only *real* way to do this would be to save the file on a readonly medium - the closest you will likely get on writeable media is to make the files immutable with `chattr` - see for example [How to make files protected?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/835964/how-to-make-files-protected)

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @steeldrivers answer, I now have a solution. (using the "`chattr +i`" command.)

Possible duplicate of [how to make files protected?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/835964/how-to-make-files-protected)

Comment: This can still be reverted though, just saying.  Because `chattr` can still be changed by `root`