# Cannot remove previously chmoded files on separate home partition after fresh install (upgrade)

Tags: partitioning, permissions

A few months ago I chmoded some files as per guides instructions and recently I found better alternatives, and yesterday I did a fresh install (upgrade) leaving home dir intact on a separate partition.
Now however, I cannot delete those files due to uuid change. I tried chmod, chown and shred, both normally and in live (install) environment, but to no avail. So, if anyone knows how to go around it, without formatting home partition, any help is most appreciated.

Comment: Can you be more specific please? what leads you to believe that the issue is "due to uuid change"? Please give examples of actual command(s) that you tried, and the resulting errors.

Comment: Before fresh upgrade I could make changes to files, even move them to other location. Now I cant do even later. Let alone former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chmodding isnt the only way to make files 'protected'. Take a look at

- [How to make files protected?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/835964/how-to-make-files-protected)

too. (keyword chattr)

Comment: Thank you for your help. That solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this solution :
https://serverfault.com/questions/35076/need-to-fix-file-permissions-in-a-users-home-directory

> find /home/user -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0775
> find /home/user -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0664

You might need sudo though :

> sudo find /home/user -type d -print0 | sudo xargs -0 chmod 0775
> sudo find /home/user -type f -print0 | sudo xargs -0 chmod 0664

Comment: That doesn't help. I always get Operation not permitted. Whether it be file or folder.

Comment: What is your distro? You might need sudo. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: My distro is ultimate edition 6.6, gamers xfce max variant.